# How to run bash script with targets?

Tags: bash, makefile, target

I remember creating Makefiles that would allow targets such as Clean or Tar that would only run the commands if the target was added to the end. Example:

Terminal

```
./myscript Clean
```

myscript

```
cd testfolder
python3 main.py

Clean:
    rm -f *.txt
```

where the rm -f *.txt line would only get run if the user added Clean to the end of the command. Just wondering if this is possible with a bash script because it would make my life easier rather than having multiple short scripts. If it isn't possible or if I didn't propose my question clearly enough just let me know! Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If you want a `make` behavior why don't you use a Makefile instead of a shell script?

Comment: Your script `myscript` does not make sense. You should get a _command not found_ error on the line `Clean:`. Please paste your code into [shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/), before posting it here.

Comment: @user1934428 Yes I know it will produce an error. The "Clean:" line is in there to show what functionality I was looking for, refer to TheAnalogyGuy's response to my post for clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass arguments to a simple bash script and use something like a case statement or an if statement - here is an example using a case statement that should work.

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# cd to the test folder
cd testfolder

# run main.py script that does blah blah
python3 main.py

# parse argument(s)
case $1 in
  Clean)
    rm -f *.txt
    ;;
  Blah)
    echo "You passed 'Blah' ..."
  ;;
  *)
    echo "Usage: $0 Clean | Blah"
  ;;
esac
```

Example (using the above contents):

```bash
# simple python script...
$ cat testfolder/main.py
print ("hello")

# (add the above contents to to a file named 'myscript')
# change the mode of the file to make it executable
$ chmod +x myscript

# generate some test files in the dir
$ touch testfolder/testfile{1..4}.txt

# show the test files
$ ls  testfolder/
main.py  testfile1.txt  testfile2.txt  testfile3.txt  testfile4.txt

# run with no args
$ ./myscript
hello
Usage: ./myscript Clean | Blah

# run with `Blah`
$ ./myscript Blah
hello
You passed 'Blah' ...

# run with 'Clean'
$ ./myscript Clean
hello

# show contents now
$ ls  testfolder/
main.py
```

If you want to see a little bit under the hood what is happening, run with `-x`

e.g.

```bash
$ touch testfolder/testfile{1..4}.txt

$ bash -x myscript Clean
+ cd testfolder
+ python3 main.py
hello
+ case $1 in
+ rm -f testfile1.txt testfile2.txt testfile3.txt testfile4.txt
```